# Issue regarding the release letter from my last company

Tags: resignation

I joined company A in Feb 2013 and resigned from there in May 2014. At that time I received all the necessary documents. Two months later, the 21st July 2014 I once again joined company A but after a period of 3 months in Oct 2014 I resigned from company A.

I was unable to serve out the 30 day notice period since I had already signed with company B where I had to start immediately. To solve this problem, I asked my previous company if I could skip the 30 day notice period if I agreed to forego 1 month of salary and they agreed, but when I joined company B and they sent a background verification mail to company A, company A sent them negative feedback saying I did not serve the notice period.

This has lead to company B firing me and in addition company A is refusing to provide the required release letter. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: I do not understand that. Your next company *knew* you would not serve your notice period with the old company and then fired you *because* you did not serve said period? That does not make sense. Did I miss something? Maybe you can add some paragraphs to make it easier to read.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: release letter = relieving letter? Lots of answers about relieving letters.

Comment: Do you have proof that company A agreed to let you end your notice period early? Even some emails that were saved? Showing that to company B may help. And when asked, company A probably only said "No, user33309 did not serve notice period", which would be true.

Comment: Why did you agree to join company B immediately before you had negotiated the notice period with company A?

Comment: There is another problem with your narrative. Has company B officially told you that you are being fired for not serving the company A's notice period? If company B asks company A whether you served notice period, they would obviously say no, because you did not. If company B is aware that you did not serve notice period *because* you had to join them immediately *and* that you offered a month's salary in lieu of it, then it sounds silly they would make an issue out of it. It thus seems more plausible company B fired you for a different reason.

Comment: My guess is the discussion about forgoing salary in lieu of notice was with a (lower level) manager, and the company HR dept had no clue and was treating him/her per company regulations. I agree with Myles answer and if you don't have it in writing, not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it in writing that an agreement was made that you would forego one month salary in exchange for not serving the notice period then that should be presented to Company B.  If you do not then it is a valuable lesson in getting things in writing.

The flip side of this is that if they are saying you were not released then you may still be entitled to that one month salary but you should contact a labor lawyer to examine the specifics of the situation with respect to local law.

Good luck.